Running out of memory when covert TFLite model (by TFLiteConverter) with UpSampling1D
Original model is as below
import logging
tf.get_logger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='testLog1.log', filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(filename)s[line:%(lineno)d] - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

inp = Input(shape=(batching_size,1))
c1 = Conv1D(2,32,2,'same',activation='relu')(inp)
c2 = Conv1D(4,32,2,'same',activation='relu')(c1)
c3 = Conv1D(8,32,2,'same',activation='relu')(c2)
c4 = Conv1D(16,32,2,'same',activation='relu')(c3)
c5 = Conv1D(32,32,2,'same',activation='relu')(c4)
dc1 = Conv1DTranspose(32,32,1,padding='same')(c5)
conc1 = Concatenate()([c5,dc1])
dc2 = Conv1DTranspose(16,32,2,padding='same')(conc1)
conc2 = Concatenate()([c4,dc2])
dc3 = Conv1DTranspose(8,32,2,padding='same')(conc2)
conc3 = Concatenate()([c3,dc3])
dc4 = Conv1DTranspose(4,32,2,padding='same')(conc3)
conc4 = Concatenate()([c2,dc4])
dc5 = Conv1DTranspose(2,32,2,padding='same')(conc4)
conc5 = Concatenate()([c1,dc5])
dc6 = Conv1DTranspose(1,32,2,padding='same')(conc5)
conc6 = Concatenate()([inp,dc6])
dc7 = Conv1DTranspose(1,32,1,padding='same',activation='linear')(conc6)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inp,dc7)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.002),loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError())
history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1)

tflite_model = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

# Full Inter post-training quantization.
tflite_model.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
tflite_model.target_spec.supported_ops = [
     tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,]
     tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS,  # enable TensorFlow ops.
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]  # use both select ops and built - ins

tflite_model.inference_input_type = tf.int8
tflite_model.inference_output_type = tf.int8
tflite_model_quant_INT8 = tflite_model.convert()

Both the keras and the TFLite models work fine .
Due to some reason, I have to replace the "Conv1DTranspose" operator with UpSampling1D & Conv1D.
And I do this by Colab T4 (System RAM 12.7 GB, GPU RAM15.0 GB).
After running, it crashes and shows running out all memory and restarts the Colab sessions.
Since it's crash due to memory, I thought to reduce the replacement Ops numbers.
Even I only replace the last one"dc7" as below, it remains crash.
def conv1d_transpose(x, filters, kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same', activation=None):
    x = UpSampling1D(size=strides)(x)
    x = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=padding, activation=activation)(x)
    return x

.....
dc7 = conv1d_transpose(conc6, 1, 32, 1, padding='same', activation='linear') # Replacement
....

I suppose the tunable parameter is same as the one with Conv1DTranspose, so I don't expect this will cause halt due to resource.
The Keras model with replacement works fine with inference,
just if I try to do "Full integer post-training quantization" then it's crashed. Instead, doing a default dynamic post-training quantization seems can be done normally.
'logging' show nothing here.
Please help if any hint or guidance. Thanks.
